# sum a value that appears on multiple rows ones per id in microsoft sql

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

I have a table that looks like below. In my query I'm sum:ing the order item value for each order item type, but I'm not sure how to summarize the providerfee per order id when the providerfee appears on multiple rows. Sum(providerfee) would give me 60 instead of 30.

Raw table (sample):

| order id | order item type | order item value | providerfee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | 300 | 30 |
| 1 | Shipping | 40 | 30 |
| 1 | Invoicefee | 30 | 30 |

Aggregated table if I would query above example table with the query I'm using now:

| noOfOrders | productAmount | ShippingAmount | InvoiceAmount | providerfee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 40 | 30 | **60** |

What value I wish to get in the providerfee column in my aggregated table instead:

| noOfOrders | productAmount | ShippingAmount | InvoiceAmount | providerfee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 40 | 30 | **30** |

Does anyone now best practice of fetching the right sum per order id from the providerfee-column? I think it won't make any sense to publish the actual query I'm writing but basically what I'm doing to fetch the amounts for order item types is:

```
    with amounts as (
        select
        case when orderItemType= 'Product' then orderItemValue else 0 end as productAmount
        ,case when orderItemType = 'Shipping' then orderItemvalue else 0 end as shippingAmount
        case when orderItemType = 'Fee' then orderItemvalue else 0 end as InvoicefeeAmount
        ,providerfee
        
    from exampleTable
    
    )
    
         select
         sum(amounts.productAmount) as productAmount
         ,sum(amounts.shippingAmount) as shippingAmount
         ,sum(amounts.invoicefeeAmount) as invoicefeeAmount
         ,sum(amounts.providerfee) as providerfeeAmount <---- This one gives me too high values since I'm summing every rows and providerfee appears on every row 

        from amounts
```

Here's a picture of how my actual table look like. Providerfee is supposed to be 638 just like invoiceAmount
[image]

One thing I also tried was a logic with row number function. But this gave me a result where three providerfees where missing. Instead of 638 I got 551. Can't see why since I counted in the raw table and got it to 638 myself. Not sure if I'm missing something logical with row number function that can have an impact on the SUM. Should I try another function to be able to pull out only one providerfee-row per order id?

```
    with amounts as (
        select
        row_number() over (partition by orderId order by orderItemTimestamp DESC) as rn
        ,case when orderItemType= 'Product' then orderItemValue else 0 end as productAmount
        ,case when orderItemType = 'Shipping' then orderItemvalue else 0 end as shippingAmount
        ,case when orderItemType = 'Fee' then orderItemvalue else 0 end as InvoicefeeAmount
        ,providerfee
        
    from exampleTable
    
    )
    
         select
         sum(amounts.productAmount) as productAmount
         ,sum(amounts.shippingAmount) as shippingAmount
         ,sum(amounts.invoicefeeAmount) as invoicefeeAmount
         ,sum(amounts.providerfee) as providerfeeAmount <---- This one gives me too high values since I'm summing every rows and providerfee appears on every row 
         ,sum(case when (amounts.providerfee is not null and amounts.rn = 1) then amounts.providerfee else 0 end) as providerfee2

        from amounts
```

Comment: Is that sample data or the expected/unexpected result? We need both anyway - [mcve].

Comment: Is it clearer now that I added the result I get vs the result I want?

Comment: Will each order always have any of the order item types? (E.g. always exactly one Product, or one fee?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grand total can be done using conditional aggregation. (Note that I here expect every Orderto have exactly one Invoicefee.)

```
select COUNT(distinct OrderId) as noOfOrders,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Product'  then orderItemValue else 0 end) as productAmount,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Shipping' then orderItemvalue else 0 end) as shippingAmount,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Fee'      then orderItemvalue else 0 end) as InvoicefeeAmount,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Fee'      then providerfee    else 0 end) as providerfee
from amounts
```

You can also add a `GROUP BY`, to get aggregation per order:

```
select OrderId,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Product'  then orderItemValue else 0 end) as productAmount,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Shipping' then orderItemvalue else 0 end) as shippingAmount,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Fee'      then orderItemvalue else 0 end) as InvoicefeeAmount,
       SUM(case when orderItemType = 'Fee'      then providerfee    else 0 end) as providerfee
from amounts
group by OrderId
```

Comment: Yes, very clever! If it would be that any of those order items for sure always appeared at least ones and only one time that would be a stable way of doing so. Maybe I have another column that indicates that there is a providerfee that I can use instead. 

Can mention that I tried with rownumber partitioned by order id and ordered by when each order item type happens, and then just sum:ed one of the rows like this: SUM(CASE WHEN (amounts.rownumber = 1 AND amounts.providerfee IS NOT NULL) THEN amountsproviderfee ELSE 0 END) AS providerfee. But this ignored three providerfees for some reason